# C++ - Convert uint8_t* image data to double** image data

Tags: c++, iphone, image, image-processing

I am working on a `C++` function (inside my iOS app) where I have image data in the form `uint8_t*`.

I obtained the image data using the code using the `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress()` method of the `iOS SDK`:

```
uint8_t *bPixels = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
```

I have another function (from a third part source) that does some of the image processing functions I would like to use on my image data, but the input for the image data for these functions is `double**`.

**Does anyone have any idea how to go about converting this?**
*What other information can I provide?*

The constructor prototype for the class that use `double**` look like:

```
Image(double **iPixels, unsigned int iWidth, unsigned int iHeight);
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about how `Image()` expects `double** iPixels` to be composed. It could be a number of different formats. Additionally, `imageBuffer` could be in multiple formats, although your code thus far implies it is encoded 32-bits per pixel. `CVPixelBufferCreate()` would have been called with the pixel format.

Answer (score 1):

Your `uint8_t *bPixels` seems to hold image data as 1-dimensional continuous array of `height*width` lenght. So to access pixel in the x-th row and y-th column you have to write `bPixels[x*width+y]`.

`Image()` seems to work on 2-dimensional arrays. To access pixel like above you would have to write `iPixels[x][y]`.

So you need to *copy* your existing 1-dimensional array to a 2-dimensional:

```
double **mypixels = new double* [height];
for (int x=0; x<height; x++)
{
    mypixels[x] = new double [width];
    for (int y=0; y<width; y++)
        mypixels[x][y] = bPixels[x*width+y]; // attention here, maybe normalization is necessary
                                             // e.g. mypixels[x][y] = bPixels[x*width+y] / 255.0
}
```

Because your 1-dimensional array has pixel of type `uint8_t` and the 2-dimensional one pixel of type `double`, you *must* allocate new memory. Otherwise, if both would have same pixel type, the more elegant solution (a simple *map*) would be:

```
uint8_t **mypixels = new uint8_t* [height];
for (int x=0; x<height; x++)
    mypixels[x] = bPixels+x*width;
```

**Attention:** beside the problem of eventually necessary normalization, there is also a problem with the indices-compatibility! My examples assume that the 1-dimensional array is stored *row-by-row* and that the functions working on 2-dimensional index with `[x][y]` (that means *first-row-then-column*). The declaration of `Image()` however, could lead to the conclusion that it needs its arrays to be indexed with `[y][x]` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a giant bunch of guesses here in hopes that this will lead you towards getting at the documentation and answering back.  If there's no further documentation, well, here's a starting point.

Guess 1) The Image constructor requires a doubly dimensioned array where each component is an R,G,B,Alpha channel in that order.  So iPixels[0] is the red data, iPixels[1] is the green data, etc.

Guess 2) Because it's not integer data, the values range from 0 to 1.

Guess 3) All of this must be pre-allocated.

Guess 4) Image data is row-major

Guess 5) Source data is BRGA

So with that in mind, starting with bPixels

```
double *redData = new double[width*height];
double *greenData = new double[width*height];
double *blueData = new double[width*height];
double *alphaData = new double[width*height];
double **iPixels = new double*[4];

iPixels[0] = redData;
iPixels[1] = greenData;
iPixels[2] = blueData;
iPixels[3] = alphaData;

for(int y = 0;y < height;y++)
{  
   for(int x = 0;x < width;x++)
   {
      int alpha = bPixels[(y*width + x)*4 + 3];
      int red = bPixels[(y*width +x)*4 + 2];
      int green = bPixels[(y*width + x)*4 + 1];
      int blue = bPixels[(y*width + x)*4];

      redData[y*width + x] = red/255.0;
      greenData[y*width + x] = green/255.0;
      blueData[y*width + x] = blue/255.0;
      alphaData[y*width + x] = alpha/255.0;
   }
 }

 Image newImage(iPixels,width,height);
```

some of the things that can go wrong.

Source is not BGRA but RGBA, which will make the colors all wrong.
Not row major or destination is not in slices which will make things look all screwed up and/or seg-fault